# compress and decode picture for max quality

Tags: android, image, bitmap

having trouble keeping an images quality while compressing > sending to sever (in BLOB format) > retrieving image > decoding BLOB > then setting bitmap.

When i take the picture on the device or choose to upload one it looks alright on the camera but once I send it to the server and get it back later the quality is garbage.

here is the code I am using while compressing the image:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and decoding:

```
    String pict = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pic");
    byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(pict, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

thanks in advanced!

Comment: Try using `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG`.

Comment: doesnt make a difference. I know PNG is lossless, but the images are still coming out pixelated.

Comment: How are you decoding the image back to a bitmap? Are you changing the size?